# Map doesnt show current location with marker

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Navigation drawer and in that one option i need to provide for Google map.In that i wan to display user's current location with continuous update in his location with a marker. Foll is my code

```
public class MapView extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

    GoogleMap m_map;
    boolean mapReady = false;
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private Marker marker;

    public MapView() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map_view, container, false);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mapReady = true;
        m_map = googleMap;

        googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity()).addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this).addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
        googleApiClient.connect();


    }






    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                gotoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 15);
            }
        };
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[2] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                showLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    public void showLocation() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && getActivity().checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

                    ) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                }, 0);
            } else {
                Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
                if (location == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
                    m_map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
                }
            }

        } else {
            Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
            if (location == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15);
                m_map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
            }

        }


    }

    public void gotoLocation(double lat, double lng, float zoom) {
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom);
        m_map.moveCamera(cameraUpdate);
        if(marker!=null){
            marker.remove();
        }


        MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lat,lng))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.bg));
        //dont put image in mipmap for marker
        marker= m_map.addMarker(markerOptions);



    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, locationListener);
    }

}

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="sawant.pritish.com.sharingfoodandhappiness.MapView.MapView">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />



</FrameLayout>
```

I have added al the necessary permissions like internet,access fine and coarse location and access network state. I have added the meta data tags and uses feature tag.Can somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by more simple solution: just call

`googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);`

in your  `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` callback after `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or                         `android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission granted. Something like that:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 101;
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private MapFragment mMapFragment;

    private void makeLocationPermissionRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        mMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    private void showCurrentPositionMarker() {
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
   }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            int locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                makeLocationPermissionRequest();
            } else {
                showCurrentPositionMarker();
            }
        } else {
            showCurrentPositionMarker();
        }
}

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    showCurrentPositionMarker();
                } else {
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```